# How to check a BLE device still connected with Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey

I've successfully connected my Delphi(FM) app to a ESP32 device and I can send commands/receive data over BLE (I am showing a message for connection status after connection is successful/unsuccessful). But problem is that, if user close/power off the ESP32 device then mobile app still shows connection established.

I've tried both [System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothConnectionState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothConnectionState) and [System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager.ConnectionState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager.ConnectionState) with a TTimer but no success.

```
if not (BLEDevice1.ConnectionState = TBluetoothConnectionState.Connected) then
  begin
  Showmessge('Connection not established!');
  // this type of control doesn't change anything.
  end;
```

Comment: BLEDevice1.OnDisconnect event?

Comment: @DaveNottage thank you for comment, I've tried this before but it wouldn't work because problem was about I didn't wait until OnDisconnect event fire (it takes too time). After waiting for a time, message has been shown. Only the problem is this control made approximately within 10-15 sec. but it seems the correct answer is your suggestion. So please can you add this as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OnDisconnect event of the Bluetooth device (TBluetoothLEDevice)